# Successor of DefaultStateKeyGenerator

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Folks,

Can somebody point me to the successor of the **deprecated** type `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.state.DefaultStateKeyGenerator`
I am moreover interested in the Reactive flavor of it.

Unfortunately, there is no mention in the oAuth2 migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I'm also looking for the same